# list is interpreted as string

Tags: python-3.x, append

I get the error saying: "'str' object has no attribute 'append'" and I don't get why because I defined the object as list, so where is the error?

```
class A:
    inputliste = []
    inputfilepath = inputfilepath
    def __init__(self,inputfilepath):                       
        self.inputfilepath = inputfilepath   

    def __init__(self,inputliste):
        self.inputliste = inputliste

    def fileopening(self):                                      
        with open(self.inputfilepath,"rb") as inputfile:
            byte = inputfile.read(1)
            while byte:
                self.inputliste.append(byte.hex())
                byte = inputfile.read(1) 

inputfilepath = C:\...
a = A(inputfilepath)
a.fileopening()
```

The error is referring to the line where it says:
`self.inputliste.append(byte.hex())`

Answer (score 0):

In your `__init__` constructor you're setting the variable `self.inputliste` to `inputliste` which is passed in the constructor. When creating a new class `A` object you're passing `inputfilepath` in the constructor and therefore overriding your `inputliste` variable with a `str` which is why it's complaining that it cannot append to a `str`

Comment: ah ok thank you very much. How would i change it though, because i need both inputfilepath and inputliste, so i can use them in other classes through inheritence etc. ?

Comment: You can have multiple parameters in a constructor, that way you can set both

Comment: i put them both in one constructor:
    def __init__(self,inputfilepath,inputliste):
        self.inputfilepath = inputfilepath 
        self.inputliste = inputliste

it give me the error "__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputliste'"

Comment: I think the required positional arguement error occurs because i didn´t run the class with A(inputfilepath,inputliste), the thing is i don´t want to because i just need  inputliste for another class through inheritence.

Comment: That's correct, but if you don't need that parameter to be passed through the constructor when why not remove it from the constructor?

Comment: You are probably right i should remove it from the constructor, the thing is i want to use this variable inputliste in another class and i thought the way to go would be to  put it in the constructor.

Comment: I think i got it now i removed inputliste from the constructor and defined my function from my other class differently to use the variable and it now works as i want to :)